# How to configure bind/named for this simple nameserver task?

Tags: dns, domain, freebsd, bind

I need to configure `bind/named` (on FreeBSD) to:

- listen on port 53 of a single IP,
- never look up records or forward any queries to any other server,
- never try and update its records from other nameservers,
- reply *"not known/refused/no records"* for absolutely any queries except a single subdomain for which it's authoritative, and for which it returns any DNS records held as usual.

Beyond this, its config need to be locked down so it can't do anything else.

It should be simple, but how do I do it? What is the simplest config that will achieve what I want?

Comment: I think "give me a premade config" is a bit outside the scope of this site.

Comment: On an unrelated note, first you must fix your subdomain delegation. NS records must not point to an IP address – they can only be indirect through another domain name.

Comment: Sorry grawity - I cut the question down a lot before I saw your comment. I've saved the original in case it needs pasting back or is more relevant than I realised - let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you with my Ansible role to [Install and configure DNS](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/freebsd-dns). Example how-to configure a domain can be found in the [vars directory](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-dns/blob/master/vars/main.yml).

To listen on port 53 of a single IP configure YOUR-IP. Port 53 is the default.

```
bsd_named_conf_listen_on: "YOUR-IP;"
```

To never look up records or forward any queries to any other server and never try and update its records from other nameservers

```
bsd_named_conf_forwarders: ""
```